# Saving data only when payment is successful

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

I am trying to create a competition registration form for my website built using WordPress. I want the form to be able to do a couple things:-

1. Get the required data from the person(Name, University etc) - Page 1.
2. Upon the click of "Submit" button, redirect them to some payment page.(I have an account with a payment service, instamojo, which allows me to create a link with pre-determined amount and even has a WooCommerce plugin)
3. Only upon successful payment Page 1 should save that data someplace where I can later access it to see who successfully registered.
4. If the payment fails, I want Page 1 to discard the data.

I am extremely new to the whole web development thing but I am getting used with the plugins and stuff. And I just want someone to point me in the right direction. That will be a huge help.

Thanks a ton for your time.

Comment: What i normally do in cases like this, i create a script and set it to run as a cronjob , when it runs , have it check if an order was placed is above 1 hour old and not completed. Then remove the order data.
Part 2 I do is creating it as a function I can hook into the failed payment hook.

Comment: How does the script check if the order was "completed"? The payment gateway just displays "Payment successful" to the user and credits the amount to me. Also, in what language do you write the script?

Comment: Using a hook like this one: woocommerce_payment_complete_order to detect if the payment is completed. And if its the cron job, then have it simply check order status. 

Language PHP like Wordpress and woocomemrce :)